# Uploading a file/image located in Angular Project Directory

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I want to upload a file which is stored in my angular assets directory. Below is the code that I use to upload files to firebase.

```
    const file = this.selectedProPic;
    const filePath = `${this.uid}/propic`;
    const fileRef = this.afStorage.ref(filePath);
    this.taskProPic = this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file);
```

Here the file variable gets assigned with the file which gets selected from the file uploader in html. i need to modify this part/'file' variable to select the file which is located at assets/img/default-avatar.jpg. I tried with toPath and pathToFileURL and also googling. but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular's [http client](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient):

```
this.http.get('assets/filename.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(data => { 
         const file = data;
         const filePath = `${this.uid}/propic`;
         this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file);
    });
```

Based on the file type you might want to set proper responseType though.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I wanted to upload an image. So I changed the responseType to 'blob'